# Are BJTs used in modern integrated circuits to the same extent as MOSFETs?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, semiconductors

On modern integrated circuits, are there as much BJT's on the chip as MOSFET transistor? If not, why?

Comment: Depends on the integrated circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very dependent on the circuit. See this reply on details why one would use one over the other:

[When is a MOSFET more appropriate as a switch than a BJT?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13079/when-is-a-mosfet-more-appropriate-as-a-switch-than-a-bjt)

For discrete transistors there are advantages to each. When we talk about ICs and VLSI systems the MOSFET is the device of choice because of the simpler manufacturing process and the fact that they are easier to miniaturize.

Answer (score 6):

No, BJT has less extent than MOSFET because BJT is used where we need more speed. 
But MOSFET is used where we want less power dissipation, low operating voltage, less noise, simple manufacturing process, low chip area and easily scalable.
Now, we use both devices as BiCMOS (BJT + CMOS) which has more speed than MOSFET and low power dissipation than BJT.
Another main application of BJT is oscillators. BJT is better than MOSFET as oscillators.

Comment: Good answer. I found a book which substantiates a lot of what you're saying, too. I've quoted the book in my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527268/26234.